# How to fire Qt Signal from mocked class that was mocked with GMock

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have a class with an interface that is doing some uploading, which is done async, when the upload finishes, it fires a signal to inform the consumer of this class that the work has been done. I'm trying to write a test for the consumer class that gets a mock injected and the basic idea was when the upload method is called, the mock should trigger the finished signal on itself. Problem is that the tested consumer doesn't get the signal. I'm either missing something or this doesn't work.
For simplicity reasons, here are some fake implementations:

The interface of the uploader:

```
#include <QObject>

class IUploader : public QObject 
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    IUploader() = default;
    ~IUploader() override = default;
    virtual void upload(int i) = 0;

signals:
    void finished(int i);
};
```

The mock:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

#include "IUploader.h"

class UploaderMock : public IUploader
{
public:
   MOCK_METHOD(void, upload, (int i), (override));
};
```

The test:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include "Consumer.h"
#include "UploaderMock.h"

TEST(Consumer, UploaderFinished_Should_TriggerCallback)
{
   // arrange
   UploaderMock uploader;

   ON_CALL(uploader, upload(11)).WillByDefault([&uploader](int i) {
      uploader.finished(i * 2);
   });
   
   Consumer consumer(&uploader);

   // act
   consumer.doUpload(11);
   
   // assert
   EXPECT_EQ(consumer.uploadResult(), 22);
}
```

Consumer.h
#include

```
#include "IUploader.h"

class Consumer : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Consumer(IUploader *uploader);
    ~Consumer() override = default;
    void doUpload(int i);
    int uploadResult() const;

private:
    IUploader *mUploader = nullptr;
    int mResult = -1;

private slots:
    void setResult(int i);
};
```

Consumer.cpp

```
#include "Consumer.h"

Consumer::Consumer(IUploader *uploader) :
    mUploader(uploader)
{
    connect(uploader, &IUploader::finished, this, &Consumer::setResult);
}

void Consumer::doUpload(int i)
{
    mUploader->upload(i);
}

int Consumer::uploadResult() const
{
    return mResult;
}

void Consumer::setResult(int i)
{
    mResult = i;
}
```

What happens is that I do see the action being triggered in the ON_CALL but I don't see any signal received by the Consumer object.

Is such a test case possible with Qt and GMock? Could it be a timing problem that the signal is processed after the test method finishes?

Comment: Yes, such a test case is possible with Qt and GMock.  Please provide the code for `Consumer`.  Please also correct the code you've provided for the test -- it doesn't compile in its current form.

Comment: Sorry, just wrote that as some kind of pseudo code, now with fixed code and consumer class. Now with the consumer class and running this most basic example I see that it works. My real use case involves an IOC Container and doesn't work. Will have a look into that.

Comment: Looks like the IOC Container was the issue or causing it. When I inject the uploader directly into the class instead of passing the IOC Container and getting the object from there, the test works. Interesting question what the issue here might be, maybe different threads in which case the Slots work async?

Comment: @DamirPorobic can you show the actual code that's causing the trouble? I.e. the one with IOC container.